# R function not found

Tags: r, mass

I have a problem calling parcoord() from StatDA in R.
My code is as follows:

```
library(StatDA)
parcoord(ice[1:8],col=c(rep(1,50),rep(2,50),rep(3,50)))
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: `parcoord` is in package `MASS`?

Comment: Oh my god. In my assignment it said the function was in `StatDA`. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: No problem. You can use `??parcoord` to search across the documentation.